# Is there a way to elide type of a composite literal by inferring types based on the type parameter of function in go?

Tags: go, generics, type-inference

```golang
type Foo struct {
    a    string
    b    int
}

type Bar[K Foo|string] struct {
    c    K
    d    string
}

func someRandomFunc (x []Bar[Foo], y []Bar[string]) {
    ///do something
}

someRandomFunc([]Bar[Foo]{{Foo{"A", 1}, "a"}, {Foo{"B", 1}, "b"}}, []Bar[string]{{{"C"}, "c"}, {{"D"}, "d"}})
```

In the above code why isnt go infering type from the function argument? Do I have to prefix each time the custom type? Why can't I do something like below?

```golang
someRandomFunc({{{"A", 1}, "a"}, {{"B", 1}, "b"}}, {{{"C"}, "c"}, {{"D"}, "d"}})
```

**Inferring type from the constrained generic type**

Go is not inferring the type from the constrained generic type as well (which it does infer if the constrained generic type is a primite types like string but not for custom types).

```golang
someRandomFunc([]Bar[Foo]{{{"A", 1}, "a"}, {{"B", 1}, "b"}}, []Bar[string]{{{"C"}, "c"}, {{"D"}, "d"}})
```

**Inferring type from the sibling inside the slice**

Go does not even infer the type from the previous sibling inside the slice

```golang
someRandomFunc([]Bar[Foo]{{Foo{"A", 1}, "a"}, {{"B", 1}, "b"}, {{"C", 1}, "c"}}, []Bar[string]{{{"D"}, "d"}, {{"E"}, "e"}, {{"F"}, "f"}})
```

Is any of the above possible with any workaround?

Comment: Please read the official spec on [Composite Literals](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals), which is the expression you're trying to use. The linked spec explains what's allowed. Note also that generics has no relevance to composite literals as far as type "elision" is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Type elisions in composite literals as of Go 1.19.4 is possible only in case of arrays, slices and maps. For structs type fields are mandatory and cannot be omitted.

**Example**

**1. Arrays and Slices - Possible**

```golang
type Foo struct {
    a    string
    b    int
}

var a []Foo = []Foo{{"A", 1}, {"B", 2}}
```

**2. Maps - Possible**

```golang
type Foo struct {
    a    string
    b    int
}

var a Map[string]Foo = Map[string]Foo{"a": {"A", 1}, "b": {"B", 2}}
```

**3. Struct - Not possible**

```golang
type Foo struct {
    a    string
    b    Bar
}

type Bar struct {
    c    string
    d    int
}

var a []Foo = []Foo{{"A", Bar{"a", 1}}, {"B", Bar{"b", 2}}}
```

In the above example it can be noted that type field Bar is not omitted. Further since go as of 1.19.4 doesn't support type elision for structs, type elision is not an option whether or not a generic type is constrained or otherwise.